# Excel: Extract Words Containing a Specific Character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Hi All,
I am having an issue when trying to extract words from an Excel file which have an @ before it. For example, if the cell has written:**

@Stack I am curious to learn about @Overflow problem

**I want to only extract Stack and Overflow from the above. I have tried the following formula:**

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A$2,FIND("@",$A$2),LEN($A$2))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

**Where $A$2 is the respective cell, but my output is only @Stack (does not deliver @Overflow). Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same formula twice and concatenate both output into same cell. Try-

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A$2,FIND("@",$A$2)+1,LEN($A$2))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)) & " " & TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A$2,FIND("@",$A$2,FIND("@",$A$2)+1)+1,LEN($A$2))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

> Edit: If you have <kbd>**Excel365**</kbd> then use below formula. It will return all word staring with `@` symbol.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '@')]"),"@",""))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! And is there the possibility to include a 3rd "@" as well?

Comment: Welceme! If it works then please mark the answer accepted (tick it). You have to use same formula for 3 times. Try `=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A$2,FIND("@",$A$2)+1,LEN($A$2))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)) & " " & TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A$2,FIND("@",$A$2,FIND("@",$A$2)+1)+1,LEN($A$2))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)) & " " & TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A$2,FIND("@",$A$2,FIND("@",$A$2,FIND("@",$A$2)+1)+1)+1,LEN($A$2))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))`

Comment: Which version of excel do you use? `Office365` may easier to find it.

Comment: Amazing! All of the formulas you provided were very helpful. I have gone ahead and accepted the answer. Thank you once again :)

Comment: @VladimirTech31 glad to know!